# spring jpa join query between table in mutlple database

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have to join 3 tables from 3 different database.

I am fetching records from table 1 (every hour and around 100K record every hour). Using the key from table1, I will have to get record from table 2 and then using key from table 2, i will have to fetch record from table 3.

I am thinking of using IN clause however I am not sure if that would be good option.

Also, Records in table2 and table3 are less in numbers and wont change frequently. So there is an option of using second level cache to get records of these two tables in cache and then filter records based on what is required for table1.

should I join tables approach or use cache for less frequently updated tables.

Please suggest.